# Can I pull an entity and it's parent components all the way up the tree of components?

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

Is it possible to pull an entity and all the component parents all the way up the tree?

A reverse recursive pull.

If not, how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datomic pull expression does support reverse attribute navigation.  Assuming your schema is like this:

```
(d/transact conn [{:db/id                 (d/tempid :db.part/db)
                   :db/ident              :node/children
                   :db/valueType          :db.type/ref
                   :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/many
                   :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}])
```

To create a tree:

```
(defn node [name & children]
  (cond-> {:db/id  (d/tempid :db.part/user)
           :db/doc name}
    children (assoc :node/children children)))

(d/transact conn [(node "L1"
                        (node "L1.1"
                              (node "L1.1.1")
                              (node "L1.1.2"))
                        (node "L1.2"
                              (node "L1.2.1")))])
```

Use query to pull component parents recursively (note the "_children"):

```
(d/q '[:find (pull ?e [:db/doc {:node/_children ...}]) .
       :where [?e :db/doc "L1.2.1"]]
     (d/db conn))
```

=>
{:db/doc "L1.2.1", :node/_children [{:db/doc "L1.2", :node/_children [{:db/doc "L1"}]}]}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this only possible if the children are of the same Entity type? If you have different types across your nesting do you need to have multiple nested pulls?

Comment: Datomic doesn't impose the concept of "type" (like table in relational database).  As long as the same relational attribute exists (:node/children in the case), the recursive syntax with pull out all related entities  (or up to a level if you indicated so).

Comment: Thanks. I added an example of what worked for me based on your answer and comment.

Comment: @stuartrexking, somehow I lost your edit after I read it.  Anyway, the way you do explicit nesting is fine if you know exactly which attribute to use at which level.  Otherwise, you may use the recursive syntax (note the "…" and a number is part of the pull syntax, please refer to the doc [here](http://docs.datomic.com/pull.html)).   E.g. [:node/attr-a {:node/_relation-attr-b …}  {:node/relation-attr-c 2}]  - this will pull :node/attr-a from the base, and recursive to arbitrary depth along :node/_relation-attr-b (…), and up to 2 levels on :node/relation-attr-c (2).

Comment: My edit was rejected. This worked for me:

`(datomic/pull db '[{:level3/_level2
                    [{:level2/_level1
                      [{:level2/_level1 [*]}]}]}]
              [:level3/id my-id])`

Is there a better way?

Comment: You may want to edit your original question sharing your schema and test data.  The expression you are using is explicit nesting which will work if you don't need recursive traversal.